# How do I import a .NET Core project to another .NET Core project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I need to use some classes from another project. How can I just import or create a reference to that project in Visual Studio?

Right now if I use "Add reference" in Visual Studio, I get the error:

```
".NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release. <br/>
 To reference other assemblies they need to be included in a NuGet package"
```

Answer (score 14):

[.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Core) works with dependencies via [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet).

If your projects are in the same solution, then yes, you can add a reference using the Visual Studio UI ("Add reference" command). A background reference will be added as a NuGet package.

Manually you can do this by adding `<ProjectReference>` section to the `.csproj` file:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
```

Otherwise, you should pack your project into a NuGet package (use the [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-pack) command) and then add it as other NuGet packages.
If you do not use any public NuGet sources, you can [host your own NuGet feed](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).

You have the next error:

```
".NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release.
 To reference other assemblies they need to be included in a NuGet package"
```

Because you are trying to add a .NET project to a .NET Core project or wise versa. Look into [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4682) for more details:

- If you're using netcoreapp then you cannot use .NET 4.x
  assemblies/packages
- If you're using net4xx then you can use the frameworkAssemblies
  section of project.json to reference DLL files that are installed by
  .NET Framework (the stuff in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache))

Comment: Thanks. But I can't use Add reference in VS. I have error: ".NET Core projects only support referencing .NET framework assemblies in this release. To reference other assemblies they need to be included in a NuGet package"

Answer (score 0):

I had a .Net core project and i wanted to create another project for services in my solution. After adding the project I added the reference as follows:

1. Right click **Dependencies** in your solution.
2. Select **Add Reference** option.
3. In the next window, in Projects dropdown select the project you want to add.

Alternatively, you can add a reference by editing the **csproj** file of the project in which you want to add the dependency/reference. Open the file and add the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\PATH\TO_YOUR_NEW PROJECT.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can add reference by adding your project name in **csproj** file. if your project in same solution

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\projectName.csproj" />
<ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectName2.csproj" />
<ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectName3.csproj" />
```