# Reference external DLL in .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've my own .dll file that I used to use with Edge.js in nodejs,
I'm trying to use it now with dot net core app, but found no where/no how to get access to it, or define it.

is there something like

```
"files":
{
    "":"MyLibrary.dll"
}
```

or like

```
using MyLibraryFile.dll
```

so that i can use the functions in it?

my assembly file structure is:
`MyLibraryFile.dll`

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class Inventory
    {
        public async Task<object> Invoke(object input)
    {
}
```

and neither `using MyLbrary;` nor  `using MyLbraryFile;`worked

I need to use this with MS Code editor, not with MS Studio.
and do not want to use `NuGet package`

Comment: I'm not familiar with .net core, but can't you just reference it like in a normal project?

Comment: NO, the `using MyLibrary;` could`t work

Comment: Not the `using`, the project's References section, right under the "Properties" one.

Comment: This is part of MS Visual studio, I need to use it in VS Code only.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**.Net Core 2** supports a direct reference to external `.dll` (e.g. Net Standard libraries, classic .Net Framework libraries). You can do it through Visual Studio UI: right click on `Dependencies->Add reference->Browse` and select your external `.dll`.

Alternatively, you can edit `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
    <HintPath>path\to\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

You can face with the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly

then just remove `\bin` folder an rebuild the project. It should fix the issue.

#### How it is possible

`Net Core 2.0` supports `.Net Standard 2.0`. `Net Standard 2.0` provides a [compatibility mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-framework-compatibility-mode) to connect `.Net Core`(.Net Standard) and `.NET Framework`. It can redirect references e.g. to `System.Int32` from `mscorlib.dll`(Net. Framework) to `System.Runtime.dll`(Net. Core). But even if your net core app is successfully compiled with dependency on external `dll` you may still have issues with compatibility during runtime if there is any API used by external library which .Net Standard doesn’t have.

Comment: Added a reference that could not be loaded. Rebuilding the project as suggested did it for me

Comment: Thanks, In my case I am using Azure DevOps and lib folder containing external assemblies was not exist on git. After the copy, it working perfectly.

Comment: How to debug this referenced dll added to the asp.net core project ?. I have a class library targeting 4.7 .net framework and a asp.net core porject both added to the same solution and this asp..net core references this class library dll when running the asp.net core app the break points never get hit .Any idea ?

Comment: Debugging should be OK. Try to check that your external `dll` is built in debug mode. Also try to uncheck "Enable Just my Code" `Tools -> Options -> Debugger`. If it doesn't help ask a separate question with details.

Comment: @AlbertK What about dependencies of the MyAssemblies.dll. For e.g. the MyAssemblies depends on MyDependency.dll (Referenced by NuGet package). Will I have to add MyDependency.dll to my .csproj <ItemGroup>? For more details about my question please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417837/system-io-filenotfoundexception-net-core-web-api-cannot-find-child-dependency link.

Comment: I have a .NET Core 3.1 project in Visual Studio 2019, and there is no "Dependencies > Add reference > Browse" option. All I see is "Add project reference", "Add shared project reference", and "Add COM reference".

Comment: Stupidly it's now under "Add Project Reference"->Browse

Comment: .net 6.0 doesn't have 'Add reference' option but editing .csproj works

Answer (score 11):

- .NET Core works with dependencies only via Nuget.
  [How do I import a .NET Core project to another .NET Core project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346172/how-do-i-import-a-net-core-project-to-another-net-core-project-in-visual-studi/38346544#38346544)
  and [Referencing standard dlls from a .NET Core XUnit project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866997/referencing-standard-dlls-from-a-net-core-xunit-project/37867569#37867569) related.
- Using VS Code you can add references to Nuget package modifying [project.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json) file. Look into "dependencies" section

  > An object that defines the package dependencies of the project, each key of this object is the name of a package and each value contains versioning information. For more information, see the Dependency resolution article on the NuGet documentation site.

  Update: Starting from .NET Core 1.1, you need to modify .csproj file by adding `<PackageReference>` section. As example:

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="6.9.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ```
- In C# `using` add namespace, not reference to assembly.

---

Comment: It is weird that I used .net core 1.0, it works fine. Then I update my framework, but the external assembly cannot be referenced. It throws assembly not found exception directly.

Comment: What is really inconvenient is that you can do "Add reference" in the C# project, and just point to a .NET Core assembly dll (that you created yourself), and it will reference it fine, and the intellisense will work for it. However the application will not run, because the referenced dll does not load (it's not in the TRUSTED_PLATFORM_ASSEMBLIES, which you will see if you set environment variable COREHOST_TRACE =1). So you spend a whole afternoon figuring out why the VS Add Reference is not working. Thank you MS.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question has already been answered, my similar problem was fixed with this method:

You can add reference external dll(external assembly .dll) in .NET Core / BlazorWebAssembly(wasm) /net 7 or.. project

1- Create a folder in the root of your project and put your dll files in it.

2- edit .csproj file and add this "ItemGroup":

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="lib\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

> All 'dll' files placed in the 'lib' folder are attached to the project
> as references.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dll with the following code:

```
[DllImport("MyLbraryFile.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
```

All you have to do is put the dll in the same directory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why did you accept this answer? This does not look like an unmanaged DLL. It looks like a .net assembly. And @Leon, why did you decide that this was an unmanaged DLL, and even more surprising, why did you opt for `SetLastError = true`? Looks like you just copied that from somewhere without really thinking about the implications. What makes you believe that this DLL does indeed call the Win32 `SetLastError()` function?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes your right, i copied this line from my own project. I use a vb.net dll there, thats why i use SetLastError = true. Indeet this is not needet here.
And I think that he accept the answer, because it works for his purpose.

Comment: The same directory as what? Solution, project, class files dir?

Comment: As with anything from Microsoft since DLLs were invented, __same directory__ refers to the same directory as the executable.  This has always been the case since the late 80s.