# Visual Studio '17 not showing assemblies in reference manager

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reference, dependencies, assemblies

I've the issue that I can't seem to figure out how to add references to certain solutions.

In most of the solutions I start in Visual Studio '17 I see "References" in my solution explorer, but e.g. for a asp.net core web api I get "Dependencies" instead. Whenever the solution shows the "References" I can view the "assemblies" tab in the "Reference Manager", but for solutions that have the "Depedencies" I can't see it (*as shown in example below*).

[image: example of what the reference manager looks like for Dependencies]

Comment: are you using a type of .NET core project template ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.Net core only works with NuGet packages.

if you have other libraries which are not part of your current `solution`. you need to `pack` it a NuGet server (You can have a local NuGet server as well)

see the following post for more information:

[Using external .dll in dot net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108106/using-external-dll-in-dot-net-core)