# Missing Assemblies Tab in Reference Manager dialog box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, assemblies

I have the latest Visual Studio Community version 2019. I have been following this awesome free series by Bob Tabor. Sorry about the link to images, but rules are rules I guess, can't add images until I have 10 points whatever that means.

I am in the section where I need to add a reference to my project.

Bob Tabor's screen:

[image: Bob Tabor's screen]

You can note that on Bob's screen he has an Assemblies tab on the dialog and a "References" section on the Solution Explorer windows. I don't have any of those.

My screen:

[image: My screen]

I have been doing some reading and I think it has to do with the new Visual Studio using .NET core instead of Frameworks? And I need to use a chicken nugget for something, but I have no idea what I am doing, I just want to do what Bob does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio '17 not showing assemblies in reference manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575251/visual-studio-17-not-showing-assemblies-in-reference-manager)

Comment: Not, really, I am not sure what to do with that information, how do I make my assemblies tab appear? I went to that post, which linked to another post, and tried Solution Explorer>Dependencies>Right Click>Add. The same Reference dialog pops up and it takes me to COM tab. 
According to Microsoft the dialog shows different categories depending on the project type:

Assemblies, with Framework and Extensions subgroups. I have none of these. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019#reference-manager-dialog-box

Comment: Basically its saying if you created a Console Project targeting Full .Net Framework (eg v4.6) then you should see the Assemblies, however if you created a Console project targeting .Net Core then you won't see the Assemblies you have to add them using NuGet for .Net Core.

Comment: There is no assemblies tab in the .Net Core project. For more info, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56774071/8335151

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be it. But now... Bob added "system.net". I search for system.net in NuGet and I don't find it. Many results pop up and I am not sure which one it is...

Comment: @ShynnSup If you want to use `system.net`, there is no need to add it in Nuget. You can use it directly. Just import it via `using System.Net;`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem, also trying to find the answear.. Now after many weeks I know. I have chosen WPF application instead of WPF APP.... is it mayby also your Problem?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31502921)