# (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) .Net core Web API cannot find child dependency (Dependencies of dependency) when added DLL by "Add Reference"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, nuget-package

I am getting **System.IO.FileNotFoundException** in my .Net Core Web API. So I've set up the below project to demonstrate the problem.

I created a.Net Standard library named **DemoLibrary** and added **QRCoder** dependency via NuGet.

*Disclaimer: Reason for choosing the QRCoder is that the Web API doesn't use it by default. I don't use it in my project. In fact, I'm getting this exception for EntityFrameworkCore.*

I created a new .Net Core Web API **DemoWebAPI** which has no other dependencies.

Then added the DemoLibrary to DemoWebAPI via Add Reference -> Browse -> DemoLibrary.dll.

This is my solution:

[image]

The DemoMethod method in Calculate class just creates the object of QRCodeGenerator.

```
public class Calculate
{
    public static string DemoMethod()
    {
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        return "";
    }
}
```

And my ValuesController in DemoWebAPI just calls the method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", DemoLibrary.Calculate.DemoMethod()  };
    }
```

Now, when I run the DemoWebAPI project I get below exception upon the call to the DemoMethod:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'QRCoder, Version=1.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I understand the fact that I have to copy the **QRCoder.dll** file somewhere. But I fail to understand where to put it. I've already tried putting it in *"bin/debug/netcoreapp2.2"* of the DemoWebAPI and *"bin/debug/netstandard2.0"* of the DemoLibrary.

But I couldn't get it working.

> Request: Please post your answer as descriptive as you can because I am new to .Net Core.

**Edit**:
I am aware of the NuGet servers. I have read topics like hosting a NuGet server in IIS and Azure. The reason behind DLL reference is I want to use my DLLs in two projects one of them is a .net core API and the other is .net framework class library which is compiled by NMAKE. I couldn't find any way to restore NuGet packages in the .MAK files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've merely added the DLL for `DemoLibrary` to your `DemoWebApi` project. That's not how you should be adding references. Since these are in the same solution, you should add a project reference. That will fix your issue.

Now, let me explain what's actually going on here. Your `DemoLibrary` has a dependency on `QRCoder`. It's a NuGet reference, which means that package will be restored (i.e. downloaded) and included in your `DemoLibrary` build output. However, it will be included as one or more DLLs along side your `DemoLibrary.dll`. When you then just reference `DemoLibrary.dll`, you're missing all these other DLLs that are part of `DemoLibrary` and thus, things don't work properly.

Now, when it comes to a project reference, things are little more complex. A project reference essentially wraps the referenced project into your other project. You can think of it as sort of a sub project. For all intents and purposes, it's like any dependency of the sub project becomes a dependency of the main project. That means that `DemoWebAPI` now technically has a NuGet package reference to `QRCoder` even though there's no explicit package reference in its project file. The dependency comes from your `DemoLibary` project. As such, with a project reference, all the necessary dependencies will be included, because it's as if the main project included those itself, by way of the sub project.

For what it's worth, you should virtually never include a DLL as a reference directly. That used to be required, but the concept of NuGet packages has all but eliminated the practice. Even if `DemoLibrary` was not in the same solution as `DemoWebAPI` (meaning you could no longer do a project reference), the correct way to use it would be to turn `DemoLibary` into a NuGet package, and then reference it in `DemoWebAPI` via a package reference, like any other NuGet package. You do not simply add the DLL.

Comment: I am aware of the project references. I set this project for demo purpose. In reality I want to reference the DLLs. The NuGet server would be my last resort. Do you mean to say that it's not possible?

Comment: You can set up your own private NuGet repository. Azure DevOps includes one for up to 5 developers for free if you want hosted. You can also reference NuGets locally or on a shared network location.

Comment: Does that mean it's not possible with dll reference?