# How do I use Linked Assemblies with Net.Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, app-config

I have recently migrated a Net.Framework 4.7 project to a Net.Core 3.1 project. In this project we used linked assemblies (I dont know if it is the rigth term, sorry). After the Migration this feature doesnot seem to work. I always get **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**. Here a short example what i am trying to achief. I got a **Consoleapplication A**

A.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <OutputPath>C:\Test\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="B">
      <HintPath>C:\Test\Lib\B.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>false</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

Code from A:

```
using B;
using System;

namespace A
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dummy B = new Dummy();
            Console.WriteLine(B.text);
        }
    }
}
```

with needs the  **class library B**

```
using System;
namespace B
{
    public class Dummy
    {
        public string text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

to function. I have signed B and set the Outputpath from it to C:\Test\Lib\ . After that i created a App.config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <linkedConfiguration href="FILE://C:/Test/A.config" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</configuration>
```

in which i linked the A.Config File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <assemblyIdentity name="B" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="ff852e2ba657dc56" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/Test/Lib/B.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Here is a picture of the Developer Command Prompt for the [public key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooik7.png).

Here is a picture of the [Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adc4o.png).

Here is a picture of the folder [Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imuv8.png).

Here is a picture of the folder [Lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4ebQ.png).

Goal for this hole procedure is to have a assembly only one time in a specific folder and no local copies.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: tl;dr; have you checked in the file properties if the files are copied to the output dir on build?

Comment: I'm curious why you want a single copy of the DLL? Disk space is cheap.

Comment: Is this enough for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50716032/1663001

Comment: What is the output path for Consoleapplication A?