# LinkedIn External Login in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, linkedin-api

I need to implement external logins and had no problem with Facebook and Google since they are supported but I'm stuck at LinkedIn. I am not exactly a beginner but I'm not very experienced at this either. Prior to this post I viewed a thousand explanations and most of them were vague, others just didn't work and others were explained for advanced people.

What I've tried:

-using cookies in the Configure method, but the methods were deprecated (I figured they were not for the 2.0 version). I also tried `app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(...)` from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.LinkedIn to no success.

-writing a service in ConfigureServices (but I didn't get it to work, I assume this is where I need to do it). I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777071/setting-up-linkedin-oauth-authentication-in-asp-net-core-2-0) but they were talking like they knew what they were doing.

**So to keep this simple, I made a default MVC ASP.NET Core 2.0 application in Visual Studio 2017. All I need to do is write stuff in Startup.cs, so my question is, what is it that I have to write and why? Thank you very much in advance.**

*PS: I would appreciate an explanation in the comment, if it's a link I probably already visited it :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers repo](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers) that provides a collection of security middleware to support social authentication providers.
Corresponding releases can be found using this link: https://www.nuget.org/profiles/aspnet-contrib (all packages that start from `AspNet.Security.OAuth`)

Unfortunately, the current master branch is only for ASP.NET Core 1.0 and so nuget packages like [package for LinkedIn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn) were published only for that version, but you may clone the repo and switch to [experimental branch](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/experimental) that is an on-going port to ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Look into [this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/170) if you need the current status of porting.

By the way, according to [this github issue](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/pull/183), the LinkedIn authentication provider has been ported already.

Comment: I think this may be what I'm looking for, but I don't really know how I can add the package to my project. Could you explain to me?

Comment: @Megid you have 2 options while the new version of Nuget package not released: clone code locally from experimental branch and then (1) add a reference to the `AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn` in your project (add`ProjectReference` in .csproj) or (2) create locally the own version of nuget package and then add a dependency to this package using own nuget feed (local feed for example). Look into [How do I import a .NET Core project to another .NET Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38346544/2833802) for more details